# Using the directory path returned from QTFile Dialogue in Python Code

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am returning the directory path from QTFile Dialogue in Pyqt:

```
dname = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Open file', '/home')
```

The path i get back is this:

```
C:\cygwin64\home\My_workspace\HFATool\raw_files
```

I want to use this path in the python code but it gives error that one slash is being read as `C:\\cygwin64\\home\\My_workspace\\HFATool\\raw_files`.

How do I change the forward slash in the mentioned path to backward slash?
When I use

```
dname = dname.replace('\','/')
```

this gives lexical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it. You need to use `\\` in your `replace` argument.

```
dname = dname.replace('\\','/')
```

This should work appropriately as a replacement.

Comment: Thank you very much Elizion, Even I was wondering what mistake am I making. Such a silly mistake.

Comment: No worries. If you found my answer sufficient, it would be nice if you accepted my answer!

Comment: I just accepted it, it did not allow me to accept before 3 minutes.